# Ansible filter list of dict when dict value is another list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a use case to filter "waf" IP alone from below yml input (zone: site9.poc.acd.xyz.in.) which is passed as Ansible parameter in my task. I don't want to loop though the list of dns_records but instead use selectattr/ map or json_query to fetch it. 
Tried below option which works but looking for better one line option if any.

```
#Test task:
- set_fact:
    zone: "{{ (myzone.dns_records|selectattr('zone','equalto','site9.poc.acd.xyz.in.')) | first }}"
- set_fact:
    wafip: "{{ zone.a | selectattr('name','equalto','waf') | map(attribute='ip') |first}}"
- debug:
    var: "{{ wafip }}"
#Output:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\"172.13.12.11\"\n"
}

# site.yml
myzone:
  dns_records:
    - zone: 78.100.in-addr.arpa.
    - zone: 92.23.172.in-addr.arpa.
    - zone: site9.poc.acd.xyz.in.
      a:
        - name: aproxy
          ip: 10.8.2.12
        - name: bproxy
          ip: 10.8.2.108
        - name: sssd
          ip: 10.8.2.109
        - name: waf
          ip: 172.13.12.11
```

Comment: `Tried couple of options` => which are ? Please edit your question and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I have included one working option above and looking for other solution(s) if any!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using a single`json_query`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Same as your above var declaration.
    myzone: {"dns_records": [{"zone": "78.100.in-addr.arpa."}, {"zone": "92.23.172.in-addr.arpa."}, {"zone": "site9.poc.acd.xyz.in.", "a": [{"name": "aproxy", "ip": "10.8.2.12"}, {"name": "bproxy", "ip": "10.8.2.108"}, {"name": "sssd", "ip": "10.8.2.109"}, {"name": "waf", "ip": "172.13.12.11"}]}]}

    # Pass target data as vars for possible future changes...
    target_zone: site9.poc.acd.xyz.in.
    target_name: waf

  tasks:

    - name: "Show {{ target_name }} ip for {{ target_zone }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?zone=='{{ target_zone }}'].a[] | [?name=='{{ target_name }}'].ip[] | [0]"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ myzone.dns_records | json_query(query) }}"
```

Result:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show waf ip for site9.poc.acd.xyz.in.] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "172.13.12.11"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```